# Jquery - Select Manipulating with Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, selection

I got a problem with my Script. Its working great with a "normal" name for the Selection, but I use a Shop CMS which names the Selection like this: "ItemOrderParams[0][g19]" and the script isnt working anymore with that name.
Can somebody solve this problem? I have no Idea how to fix it.

```
$("input[id=steckdose]").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).is(":not(:checked)"))
      $(function() {
          $('[name=ItemOrderParams[0][g19]]').val( '3' );
      })
});

$("input[id=steckdose]").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
      $(function() {
        $('[name=ItemOrderParams[0][g19]]').val( '2' );
      })
});
```

--

```
<select name="ItemOrderParams[0][g19]">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2" selected="1">Green</option>
  <option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use quotes when an attribute value contains special characters (like `[` & `]`)

```
$("input[id=steckdose]").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).is(":not(:checked)"))
        $(function() {
            $('[name="ItemOrderParams[0][g19]"]').val( '3' );
    })
});
$("input[id=steckdose]").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(function() {
            $('[name="ItemOrderParams[0][g19]"]').val( '2' );
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Escape the brackets

```
$('[name=ItemOrderParams\\[0\\]\\[g19\\]]')
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, i gave rep to Jason since hes new and had none but your answer is great too, i use your solution.Anyway much thanks :)